# Construct Socket Object by File Descriptor

Tags: sockets, d, file-descriptor, dmd, unix-socket

I have a file descriptor (0/stdin) that I want to construct a Socket object of in D. How would I do this? There doesn't seem to be an appropriate constructor for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a constructor marked "use an existing socket handle", which takes a socket_t. You can cast an int to socket_t (socket_t is an enum based on int on Unix systems).

```
    // it requires an address family but i don't think it matters much
    auto socket = new Socket(cast(socket_t) 0, AddressFamily.INET);
```

That will get you constructed, though then using it results in "Socket operation on non-socket" errors, because D's Socket calls send() and recv() rather that write() and read(), so I'm not sure how to actually make it useful...

Comment: Well it worked fine for me! My application gets run so the standard input stream actually is a socket. Didn't really think socket_t would be a file descriptor though.

Comment: Ah, of course, pretty cool. BTW if you want to go the other way, there's a method called Socket.handle() that returns a socket_t. It will implicitly cast to int in some circumstances, but if not you can explicitly cast it too and then use regular unix file functions on it.